# Is there something which will block liquids but is dissolved by blood?

Tags: water

Is there a material which can be applied to a surface that will block liquids but is dissolved by blood?

The idea is to use the liquid to close a circuit, but only if blood is present.

I'm wondering if there is something I can coat on the circuit to act as a barrier preventing other liquids from reaching the circuit, but that would react to the chemical components of blood by dissolving, allowing the blood to reach and close the circuit.

One application might be in a bandage, to detect if a wound has reopened. The number of liquids in that context is pretty limited. A limited number of false positive edge cases is also acceptable

Comment: What do you mean by "block" ? And what class of liquids ? I assume if blood dissolves it, it won't "block" blood.

Comment: I've elaborated on the question in the body of the post.

Comment: There lots of substances, that are soluble in water (and also in blood) but insoluble in some of other liquids.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I'm wondering if there is something that reacts specifically to the makeup of blood (as opposed to water), like hydrogen peroxide, but with the effect of dissolving, which can be used as a coating.  I've further elaborated the question.

Comment: There is probably nothing that will react *only* to blood that might not be fooled by *some* other material. How specific must it be (e.g. human blood, mammal blood, arthropod blood)? What is the environment in which it must operate?

Comment: I imagine you are right. One application might be in a bandage, to detect if a wound has reopened. The number of liquids in that context is pretty limited. A limited number of false positive edge cases is also acceptable.

Comment: You state this material is to be used to form a protective layer over a sensor, and should react to blood by dissolving. Please tell what should be the reaction to: lymphatic fluid, puss, sweat, water, alcohol, iodine solution.

Comment: Ideally the barrier would prevent the listed fluids from reaching the circuit, but if prevented some but not all it would still be of interest.